# Looping - I am just struggling with this

Tags: php, mysql

OK, I have stared at this code for hours now scratching my head knowing that there is a way to do what I need to do but am going loopy trying to figure it OUT :/

Basically I have images within a subfolder and each subfolder has a view. What I need to do is output the names of the files with an appended number in each subfolder with each view.

Now I have the loop working for appending the number to the filenames with a single subfolder type, but what I want to do is iterate trough each subfolder and out put the same thing but for every subfolder instead of just one.

```
$ticker = "RRST";
$i = 0;
$last = '';

$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM baseimage JOIN art ON base_folder = series_code WHERE art.ticker = '$ticker' ORDER BY base_folder" );
if( !$query ) {
 die( mysql_error() ); 
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

if( $row['COUNT(base_folder)'] < 1 && $row['image_type'] == 'B' && $row['view'] == 'FF' ) {
    if( $last !== $row['base_folder'] ) {
         $i = 0;
    }
   echo $row['base_folder']."-".$i++;

           echo "<br />";
    $last = $row['base_folder'];
     echo "<hr />";
}

}
```

Now this is working but I would like to change this line:

```
if( $row['COUNT(base_folder)'] < 1 && $row['image_type'] == 'B' && $row['view'] == 'FF'
```

so that the it loops through the multiple ['image_type'] and the multiple ['view'], unstead of hard coding the **image_type** and **view**

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a recursive function. You would abstract your sql query into a function that fetches where parent = x. then make the function build an array or object and either recursively call itself if the query returned results or return the object or array if it had no results... Make sense? Well, hopefully it at least gets you started. I'm in the middle of work right now so I can't type it all out.

Comment: Oh my goodness I am going to have to decipher what you just said, but I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: It might actually help to know the data structure you're working with. The columns for baseimage and art, I mean. My suggestion above only helps if you are storing each folder as its own row and specifying a parent. But if you're not storing the data that way, a recursive function would be pointless.

Comment: So, you are asking then for image_type and view to not be static. But, you do not specify if these are from an expected data set. Like - is it always A, B, C or D? Or is it dynamic and could be anything? If it is set, you can use switch cases to build your results. switch($row['image_type']){ 
case 'A': 
//do something 
break; 
case 'B': 
//do something else 
break; } **** please excuse bad formatting. My whole response should not have been in the form of comments.

Comment: Yes it could be anything. Right now there is just a limited data set but to scale it will have to expand to more. so here is the data structure: 

Table name: baseimage
columns: basefolder, graphic, image_type, view

The image_type and view are the ones that can potentially grow

Answer (score 0):

You could set the expected values of image_type and view in an array and loop through it

Comment: OK I can try to write that. Thank you.